# How do i approach finding the number of equivalence classes of a relation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

(Question too long to post as title) The question is, Let S = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} and let T = {2,4,6,8}. Let R be the relation on P(S) defined by for all X, Y ∈ P (S), (X, Y ) ∈ R if and only if |X − T| = |Y − T| and i have to find the number of equivalence classes. I had to initially prove it was an equivalence relation which i dont think i had trouble with but i'm struggling to understand how to approach solving this? I looked up what an equivalence class is again and it makes sense when it was such a simple example like for instance when a set of the relation was given to me and all i had to do was check for each x in the original set which other x did it have a relation with and then find the distinct relations. However, i am struggling to understand how to apply it here to such a larger scale and more complex problem.

In this case two elements or subsets of S in P(S) are related if the elements in X and not T give a cardinality equal to the elements in Y and not T? is this the correct understanding? Then to find the number of equivalence classes i have to do what? I dont really get how to start the process any help is appreciated thank you!

Could someone perhaps explain what an equivalence class would mean in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  for any subset $X, |X-T|$ is the number of odd elements of $X$.  How many choices are there among the subsets of $S$ for the number of odd elements?

Comment: Okay so there are 5 different choices since there are 5 odd numbers

Comment: True there are $5$ odd numbers, but there are $6$ choices because you could have none.

Comment: Wait thats it? I am so confused that makes sense but could you explain how that is an equivalence class? Oh wait is each equivalence class would be like an equivalence class with only 1 odd number another with only 2 etc until 5 and then like you said a class with none. In this case the types of odd numbers is not important like the amount of odd numbers is? Why

Comment: That is right because of the definition in terms of the size of the set.  You segregate all the elements of $P(S)$ by the number of odd elements, which gives us six piles.  Once you see that, the proof that it is an equivalence relation and each pile is an equivalence class is easy.

Comment: Okay i guess that makes sense but if i was asked like for an equivelance class of the empty set or for instance the equivalence class of {1,2,3,4} how would i be able to find the number of elements in that class? If we just established that there are 6 different equivalence sets each with a different number of odd numbers then where does the empty set fall or {1,2,3,4} fall, like 1,2,3,4 has 2 odd numbers does that mean it falls in the equivalence class with 2 odd numbers? If it does i have to take into account the actual numbers now?

Comment: Or like for {1,2,3,4} am i finding how many subsets of S,Y have a cardinality of 2? But that would mean y would be anything with atleast 2 things not in common with T so i guess i'm confused by how we defined the 6 equivalence classes but now we are asked a specific equivalence class and how does that connect to the other 6 we defined

Comment: Wait what? {1,2,3,4} falls under one of the 6 predefined equivalence classes [2] where it needs to have 2 odd numbers right? I dont understand what Y is either, X and Y are related if the cardinality of X and not T is equal to cardinality of Y and not T. Am i not trying to find the number of subsets, Y that make fall under equivelance class [2]?

Comment: $\{1,2,3,4\}$ has two odd elements, so it is in the class of subsets with two odd elements.  Any other subset with exactly two odd elements is related to it.  You choose any two odd numbers and any combination of even numbers to make one.  There are ${5 \choose 2}=10$ choices for the pair of odd numbers and $2^4$ choices for the even numbers, so $160$ subsets in the class of two odd numbers.

Comment: Yeah thats what i got for that one thanks a lot, i understand it and you've helped a lot, i'm just worried i'm not sure if i understand equivalence classes very well as a general concept. In this specific example where they are defined by cardinality i got it now. So as a general idea, equivalence classes is just dividing the possible elements of a relation based on a shared thing like in this case # odd numbers and then we can find elements in a specific equivalence class by relating back to which one of the major equivalence class it falls into and then we count, right?

Comment: Yes.  Because equivalence relations are transitive, any chain of related elements are all related to each other.  It means they separate the set into disjoint subsets.  In problems like this you need to find the unifying idea behind those subsets.